# Google Maps and CSS transform makes page blur

Tags: html, css, google-maps, transform

I have used CSS Transform technique to center a div both horizontally and vertically. This works as expected, however on pages that contain Google Maps iframe, the whole page goes blurry.

You can view the with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0rfxnyrd/11/) link. 
It appears the issue is only visible on Chrome (tested on both Mac OS X and Windows 7)

HTML:

```
<div id="location" class="card x2">                 
    <h2>Location</h2>

    <div class="box">
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
            <span itemprop="name">Title goes here</span>
            <span class="hours break">
                <span class="highlight">Hours:</span>
                <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Su-Th 17:30-23:30">Sun-Thur 5:30pm - 11:30pm<br>
                <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Fr-Sa 17:30-00:00">Fri-Sat 5:30pm - 12:00am
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.535006800354!2d-0.11951899999999999!3d51.5034!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487604b900d26973%3A0x4291f3172409ea92!2sLondon+Eye!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1410900461451" width="300" height="220" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    background-color: #1d1d1d; /* IE fallback */
    background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.95);
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0  auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    padding: 30px 35px;
    outline: 2px solid #3B3A37;
    outline-offset: -9px;
    width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: This is because transform allows for [subpixel positioning](http://dropshado.ws/post/12243351506/subpixel-positioning-with-css-transforms-and-type), resulting in anti-aliasing kicking in and blurring the page. If you want to prevent blurring, you might have to rely on other methods, such as table-cell display.

Comment: @Terry I don't really want to use table-cell, its just too messy especially if I have other content on the page. I've tried using flex-box but I am getting the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0rfxnyrd/12/)**

And here's the CSS that's pertinent:

**CSS**

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

**CSS Specifically for text in Chrome**

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Those are CSS rules designed to manage 3d transforms, which webkit based browsers tend to fuzz when rendered.  Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

The webkit font smoothing is specifically to prevent the blur on text for subpixel rendering on transforms in Webkit browsers.  If you run into this problem, that should work.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: Everything within the `location` div

Comment: Check my edit.  That should handle the text.  The rest should handle elements within the div, but none will be perfect due to there being no sure-fire solution for subpixel rendering.  I'd recommend using non-percentage based transforms instead.

Comment: Hmm not sure why I left that line out of my original fiddle, but I actually had this in there already and it didn't make a difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Really?  I'm looking at the fiddle and I'm not seeing any text blur.  Best of luck finding your solution.  There are none I know of outside of those.